# Mule Dataweave accesing data with wildcard

Tags: mule, dataweave

Is it possible to access data with wildcard in dataweave?

I have my payload as **Entry_1_m1,Entry_2_m1,Entry_3_m1**
Entries will be dynamic there might be other entry as Entry_1_m2,Entry_2_m2,Entry_3_m2.
So I should be able to get the values irrespective of last number that is I should get the value of (Entry_1_m*). Is it possible in dataweave?

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/java
%output application/xml
---
{
    Employee:{
        empRequest:{
            ReqNumber:payload.RequestNumber,
            Reasons:{
                Entry:payload.Entry_1_m1,
                Entry:payload.Entry_2_m1,
                Entry:payload.Entry_3_m1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pluck](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-operators#pluck) operator to get list of keys which will help you to map all fields starting with `Entry_1_m`. Following code worked for me

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/java
%output application/xml
%var keys = (payload pluck $$) filter ($ startsWith 'Entry_1_m')
---
{
    Employee:{
        empRequest:{
            ReqNumber:payload.RequestNumber,
            Reasons: {(keys map {
                Entry:payload[$]
            })}
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I have 3 Entries (Entry_1_m,Entry_2_m,Entry_3_m)... writing 3 filters for 3 entries wont be a impact?? as there will be only one occurence for each Entry i.e., there will be only one record with Entry_1_m2 and one record with Entry_2_m2 and so on... Also I'm interested only until Entry_3_m

Comment: You dont have to write 3 filters. Just add or condition to existing one this will resolve your problem. Something like `%var keys = (payload pluck $$) filter (($ startsWith 'Entry_1_m') or ($ startsWith 'Entry_2_m') or ($ startsWith 'Entry_3_m'))`